# Small issue in javascript array object logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an json array as below.If I find atleast one object with status as Active I need to set response =true or else false.I tried below but didnt worked .can someone help.

```
arr=[{"id":"1","status":"active"},{"id":"2","status":"complete"},
{"id":"3","status":"complete"}]
for (var i = 0; i < arr.len; i++) {                          
    if (arr[i].status == "active") {
        response = true;
    } else {
        response = false;
    }
}
console.log(response);
```

Comment: Use `i<arr.length`

Comment: @Riddler issue here is if have array as active,complete,complete..It is giving me as false....But in case Iam having complete,complete,active It is giving me true..Ideally it should give me true in any case

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array#some` to check if **at least** one element got `status` property with `active` value.

```js
var arr = [{"id":"1","status":"active"},{"id":"2","status":"complete"},
{"id":"3","status":"complete"}],
    response = arr.some(v => v.status == 'active');
    console.log(response);
```

Comment: `v.status == 'active' ? true : false;` -> `v.status == 'active;'`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You set your `response` to `true`, don't break the loop and then set it to `false` again when you meet another value.

You may simply **set initial condition and then `break`** when you find an item. You can actually even not break when you find an item, but it is useless to continue iteration when already found an item.

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "1",
    "status": "active"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "status": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "status": "complete"
  }
];

var response = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].status == "active") {
    response = true;
    break;
  }    
}

console.log(response);
```

Another elegant way is to use function and make **a short-circuit return**:

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "1",
    "status": "active"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "status": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "status": "complete"
  }
];

function hasActiveStatus(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].status == "active") {
      return true;
    } 
  }
  
  return false;
}

var response = hasActiveStatus(arr);
console.log(response);
```

Note that you had `.len` for some reason, I have replaced it with correct `.length`.

Even more elegant way is to use **`Array.prototype.some`**:

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "1",
    "status": "active"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "status": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "status": "complete"
  }
];

var response = arr.some(function(x) { return x.status === "active"; });
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = false;
var arr=[{"id":"1","status":"active"},{"id":"2","status":"complete"},
{"id":"3","status":"complete"}]
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {                          
    if (arr[i].status == "active") {
        response = true;
        break;
    } 
}
console.log(response);
```